# A problem from Graph Theory.

Tags: graph-theory

**Prove that if a graph of order 3n (n ≥ 1) has n vertices of each of the degrees n − 1, n and n + 1,
then n is even.**

Answer (score 1):

For any graph , the number of edges is half the sum of degrees of all vertices, and must be a whole number. On calculation we find $ E = \frac{3n^2}{2} $ . Thus 2 divides n and the number of vertices is even.